# Use of comma and its effect on the meaning

Tags: commas

I have two sentences with a difference in the meaning because of the comma’s usage, but I don’t remember what was the meaning of each! Please help me to know the meaning of each. Thank you!

> 1. My sister, Grace, lives in Toronto.
> 2. My sister Grace lives in Toronto.

Comment: Thy could have exactly the same meaning. But the first one could mean that you are talking to someone called Grace about your sister.

Answer (score 3):

According to the convention of traditional grammar, a comma should be used to present nonessential information—and if there is no comma, the same information is considered essential.

In the case of your two sentences:

> 1. My sister, Grace, lives in Toronto.

The use of the commas indicates that you only have one sister. Providing the name isn't necessary because the *essential* meaning of the sentence would be understood if you hadn't provided her name:

> My sister lives in Toronto.

The use of the commas is the equivalent of this:

> My sister (whose name happens to be Grace) lives in Toronto.

---

> 2. My sister Grace lives in Toronto.

Here, the *lack* of commas implies that you have at least two sisters. You are providing the name in order to give *essential* information that restricts the subject of the sentence to a *particular* sister.

In other words, it could be followed by something about *another* sister:

> My sister Audrey lives in Montreal.

However, if you do have more than one sister, and you phrase the sentence differently, you certainly don't need to provide a name:

> One of my sisters lives in Toronto.

---

I've had a couple of comments mention another use of commas. I had been aware of it, but I didn't mention it because I didn't consider it part of a direct contrast between the two.

In short, if you know somebody named Grace, and you are addressing them explicitly by name, their name could be used as in interjection in the middle of the sentence.

In other words:

> Grace, my sister lives in Toronto.
>   → My sister, Grace, lives in Toronto.

However, you could also say this (for the same reasons):

> My sister Anne, Grace, lives in Toronto.

Here, you have more than one sister, and the one you're talking about is Anne. At the same time, you are making an interjection to address Grace, to whom you are talking.

The interpretation of this is still feasible, but I think it would be at the point where it would be too confusing to let stand as written—even if you knew that the person being spoken to was Grace.

Comment: That's right, but you forgot to add the suggestion that James Random had made: that the person is talking to Grace. That's another possibility.

Comment: Very good answer, plus one, (which ia an example of commas marking parenthesis). However there is another way in which the "my sister Grace lives in Toronto" works which is the opposite of your example. If your wife was called Grace and you had a sister called Grace you would often need to distinguish between them even when talking to people who know you all well. You could do this by saying "My sister Grace has just got a job with the tax office. Grace, my wife, is still working as an accountant.

Comment: @BoldBen That's interesting, but If I were combining those sentences in that situation, I would make the second one *Grace my wife*, without the commas, because there are more than two Graces and *my wife* is restricting it to a particular one—your wife.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thinking about it you're right. Although my cousin has a brother and a partner with the same name and she usually says things like "Jim, my brother, went to London last week" pausing where I've put the commas so I was subconsciously doing what she does.

Comment: @BoldBen I actually don't think there is a 1-1 correspondence between the written convention of the restrictive and how people talk. As you indicate, people will *say* "Jim, my brother," or "Jim—I mean my brother Jim—." It's not really natural to *speak* in a restrictive way.  I think you're right that we normally do pause—which, if represented in *transcription*, would be the nonrestrictive form. This is one of those situations where written language doesn't quite match spoken language.

Comment: @JasonBassford Absolutely, the idea that punctuation is just a way of representing pauses and breaths in speech is incorrect; for me it's more to do with separating meaning. However I do fall into the "a comma is a chance to breathe" error occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to English Language Usage (ELU), Rima.  Could you explain what you think the different meanings are?  The comma has more than one use.  Punctuation is a fairly modern thing, considered in generations.  Chinese texts, the Torah, the Odyssey, Plato's Republic or Livy's history of Rome had no punctuation.  Even written words were not separated.  As you know, even today, speakers of most or all languages do not consistently separate all their words.

Wikipedia makes the point well.

> Ancient Chinese classical texts were transmitted without punctuation. ... Punctuation is historically an aid to reading aloud. The oldest known document using punctuation is the Mesha Stele (9th century BC). This employs points between the words and horizontal strokes between the sense section as punctuation.

But even this was not for a long time common.  It began to be introduced as a way to assist reading aloud, particularly in drama, where it could act as a guide *how a passage should be read*.

Even today, the main function of punctuation is to clarify how a passage is to be read.  For example, speech marks are used to show the parts of a sentence that is represented as being spoken by somebody.  Other marks have to do with points of a sentence in which a pause is indicated.  So the comma indicates a short pause, but it also indicates that something is coming that carries on the grammar or sense of the sentence.  So:-

> Would you like
>    some apples Grace

makes you stop and wonder.  What have apples and Grace got to do with each other?  We can see it is a question, so the lack of a question mark does not matter, except that if the speaker continues, we may have difficulty being sure where the question ends.

> Would you like some apples Grace I wonder if you need me to buy some I shall be going to the shops after I have made the beds I am baking a cake

This can now be read in more than one way, so that punctuation will help me to understand exactly.

> Would you like some apples, Grace?  I wonder if you need me to buy some: I shall be going to the shops after I have made the bed. I am baking a cake.

But it could be that someone else (perhaps your children) look as if they might like an apple.  So you ask them and then turn to Grace and ask her if she wants you to buy some

> Would you like some apples?   Grace, I wonder if you need to me to buy some.  I shall be going to the shops after I have made the bed.  I am baking a cake. .

So the comma after Grace is used to indicate that Grace is second person (Latin 'vocative), indicating the person being spoken to.

In fact there is further ambiguity in the rest of the passage I have made up.  I could be saying: "I shall be going to the shops.  After I have made the made the bed, I am baking a cake."  There is a slight non-sequitur, but the speaker might be implying that after **that** he would go to the shops.

So punctuation marks act more as *signposts*.  They tells us when we have come to the end of something and give us information about the sort of thing we can expect to follow. In fact, the Greeks did have their own kind of signposts, which were called *particles*.  A particle is a very short word (usually little more than two letters). For example, 'te' (τε) after a word will tell you that a conjunction ('and') is coming further along the sentence.  Sometimes it is translated as 'both...and' but that is not strictly right.  Similarly, the word 'men' (μεν) is used to warn the reader that there is a 'but' (δε) coming further along in the sentence.  Again, old-fashioned literal translators have translated this particle with the clumsy phrase *on the one hand*, but that is not what it means:  it does not have meaning, it **modifies** how we understand the sentence.  So it is very like punctuation.

So if we put a question mark after your sentence 2

> My sister lives in Toronto?

It is no longer a statement, but a question implying at least surpise and possibly disbelief.  It tells is that the speaker had no idea her sister lives in Toronto.  But it does not ***mean*** that.  If I: she knew all along where her sister lives, she is not (legally at least) **lying**, though she might be being less than honest.

So, Rima, your sentence 1 is ambiguous.  It could mean that your sister, **who is called Grace**, lives in Toronto.  In that case, the commas are telling you that the proper name is in apposition to 'sister'.  But it could mean that it is to Grace that you are talking and that you are telling Grace where your sister (probably not called Grace) lives.  Commas will not help you to decided which is what is meant.

Sentence 2, without the commas, is equally ambiguous.  So you could say that the lack of commas does not help or hinder understanding.  But it does violate a convention of punctuation, that a phrase in apposition should come within commas.